# Different results using numpy.in1d() with an array and with its single elements

Tags: python, numpy

I'm writing a code in Python and I'm having a few problems. I have two arrays, let's say A and B, both of them containing IDs. A has all IDs, and B has IDs belonging to a group. What I'm trying to do is to get the positions of the elements of B in A using the code:

```
>>> print B
[11600813 11600877 11600941 ..., 13432165 13432229 13434277]
>>> mask=np.nonzero(np.in1d(A, B))
>>> print A[mask]
[12966245 12993389 12665837 ..., 13091877 12965029 13091813]
```

But this is clearly wrong, since I'm not recovering the values of B. Checking if I was using `numpy.in1d()` correctly, I tried:

```
>>> mask=np.nonzero(np.in1d(A, B[0]))
>>> print A[mask]
[11600813]
```

which is right, so I'm guessing there is a problem with 'B' in `numpy.in1d()`. I tried using the boolean `np.in1d(A, B)` directly instead of converting it to indices but it didn't work. I also tried using `B = numpy.array(B)`, `B = list(B)`, and none of them worked.

But if I do `B = numpy.array(B)[0]`, `B = list(B)[0]` it still works for that element. Unfortunately I can't do a 'for' cycle for each element because `len(A)` is 16777216 and `len(B)` is 9166 so it takes a lot of time.

I also made sure that all elements of B are in A:

```
>>> np.intersect1d(A, B)
[11600813 11600877 11600941 ..., 13432165 13432229 13434277]
```

Comment: The output you show is only wrong if `A` is sorted in the same way as `B`. Is it? If not, you'll get the values from `B`, but in the order given by `A`. Since the output you show is truncated, it's quite possible that all the values in `B` appear in `A[mask]`, but in a different order.

Comment: Are IDs in A unique? If then, A[mask] has the same IDs as B, but in diffrent order.

Comment: A[mask] and B have no elements in common, I checked it using `np.intersect1d()`, which means that they are sorted in the same way.

Comment: Although you have a working solution, the fact that `A[mask]` and `B` have no elements in common suggests that there's something more to this problem than you've stated in your question. I can't reproduce that behavior at all; for all data I try, `len(np.intersect1d(A[np.in1d(A, B)], B)) == len(B)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `numpy.argsort`, `numpy.searchsorted` to get the positions:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.unique(np.random.randint(0, 100, 100))
B = np.random.choice(A, 10)

idxA = np.argsort(A)
sortedA = A[idxA]
idxB = np.searchsorted(sortedA, B)
pos = idxA[idxB]
print A[pos]
print B
```

If you want faster method, consider using pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Index(A)
pos = s.get_indexer(B)
print A[pos]
print B
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked in a decent amount of time.
Though I still don't know what was the error when using numpy.in1d()

Comment: `numpy.in1d()` doen't work because it lost the value order in B.